# Centos cgconfig fails to start

Tags: linux, configuration, centos, docker, system-administration

I need docker installed on one of my servers, and whenever I try to start the docker service, it fails because of cgconfig. Cgconfig throws the following error:

```
Starting cgconfig service: Error: cannot mount cpu to /cgroup/cpu: No such file or directory
/sbin/cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Cgroup mounting failed
Failed to parse /etc/cgconfig.conf or /etc/cgconfig.d      [FAILED]
```

I'm running CentOS 6.5 Final with the following /etc/cgconfig.conf file:

```
mount {
    cpuset  = /cgroup/cpuset;
    cpu     = /cgroup/cpu;
    cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
    memory  = /cgroup/memory;
    devices = /cgroup/devices;
    freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
    net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
    blkio   = /cgroup/blkio;
}
```

I appreciate any responses

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use cgroups on newer versions of CentOS you need to install `libcgroup` as well as `libcgroup-tools`:

```
$ sudo yum install libcgroup
$ sudo yum install libcgroup-tools
```

To create group use `cgcreate`, e.g.:

```
$ sudo cgcreate -g memory,cpu,blkio,cpuset:userlimited
```

To verify that `/etc/cgconfig.conf` is correct use `cgconfigparser`

```
$ cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
```

For details check: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cgroups

Note: In CentOS 6 and earlier versions one only needed to install `libcgroup`

Answer (score 0):

This error may be due to kernel you are using is booted with cgroup_disable=memory **and/or** /etc/cgconfig.conf 
contains "memory=/cgroup/memory", in your case you may solve this by commenting out "memory  = /cgroup/memory" from cgconfig.conf.

You can also refer [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/docker-user/_lBT0WYpTPs/_mjmi8S7m4sJ) or [2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-limit-resources-using-cgroups-on-centos-6) for more information.