# cgconfig service won't start up

Tags: linux, centos7, mount, cgroups

I have already referenced this post: [Centos cgconfig fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796622/centos-cgconfig-fails-to-start)

I have a centos 7 machine. I've tried commenting out and leaving in memory in the following /etc/cgconfig.conf file:

```
mount {
        cpuset  = /cgroup/cpuset;
        cpu     = /cgroup/cpu;
        cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
        memory  = /cgroup/memory;
        devices = /cgroup/devices;
        freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
        net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
        blkio   = /cgroup/blkio;
}
```

I've also manually created that directory structure. When I run `service cgconfig start`, `systemctl status cgconfig.service` gives me this:

```
 cgconfig.service - Control Group configuration service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cgconfig.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-03-14 20:27:40 EDT; 18s ago
  Process: 6713 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf -L /etc/cgconfig.d -s 1664 (code=exited, status=101)
 Main PID: 6713 (code=exited, status=101)

Mar 14 20:27:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Control Group configuration service...
Mar 14 20:27:40 localhost.localdomain cgconfigparser[6713]: /usr/sbin/cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Cgroup mounting failed
Mar 14 20:27:40 localhost.localdomain cgconfigparser[6713]: Error: cannot mount cpu to /cgroup/cpu: Device or resource busy
Mar 14 20:27:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: cgconfig.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=101/n/a
Mar 14 20:27:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Control Group configuration service.
Mar 14 20:27:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit cgconfig.service entered failed state.
Mar 14 20:27:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: cgconfig.service failed.
```

I've also tried to look at `/proc/mounts` to perhaps unmount cpu.

Any help to get the cgconfig service to start would be helpful.

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has suggestions for other SE sites where this question may be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ lssubsys -a
cpu,cpuacct
```

[image]
If is a cosubsystem like 'cpu,cpuacct', must mount in the same hierachy (for cg).

Comment: sorry, write error; 'hierarchy'  -->  ‘cpu,cpuacct’

Answer (score 0):

Running on **`Ubuntu`** I could resolve the same issue by installing the **`libcgmanager`** which provides the **`daemon` `cgmanager`**.